# Trouble with Traefik Not Routing Traffic to FastAPI Backend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, traefik, lets-encrypt

I've set up a FastAPI application and I am using Traefik v2.9 as a reverse proxy to route traffic to it. Both services are running inside Docker containers on an Ubuntu machine. Although both services are up and running, I'm unable to route any traffic through Traefik to my FastAPI backend. When I try to access my Traefik dashboard, I receive a "Bad Gateway" response.

Here are some details:

- Both containers are running and are connected to the same Docker network.
- The FastAPI container is running without any issues, and is definitely listening on port 80.
- I've verified that the FastAPI service can be accessed directly by bypassing Traefik.
- I'm using a docker-compose.traefik.yml file to configure Traefik, and a seperate docker-compose.yml to configure the middleware.
- I need to load in some AI models so FastAPI takes one or two minutes to start-up.

Here is my **docker-compose.traefik.yml** for the Traefik service:

```
services:
  traefik:
    # Use the latest V.2.9.x Traefik image availible
    image: traefik:v2.9
    ports:
      # Listen on port 80, default for HTTP, necessary to redirect to HTTPS
      - 80:80
      # Listen on port 443, default for HTTPS
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    labels:
      # === DASHBOARD ===

      # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Define the port insider of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.http.services.traefik-dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTP
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.rule=Host(`traefik.gumbo.monster`)
      # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      # traefik-https the actual router using HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.rule=Host(`traefik.gumbo.monster`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.tls=true
      # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver created below
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.tls.certresolver=le
      # Use the special Traefik service api@internal with the web UI/Dashboard
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.service=api@internal
      # https-redirect middleware to rediret HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # traefik-http set up only to use the middleware to redirect to https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-http.middlewares=https-redirect
      # admin-auth middleware with HTTP Basic auth
      # Using the environment variables TRAEFIK_USERNAME and TRAEFIK_PASSWORD
      - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_USERNAME?Variable not set}:${TRAEFIK_PASSWORD?Variable not set}
      # Enable HTTP Basic auth, using the middleware created above
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-dashboard-https.middlewares=admin-auth
    volumes:
      # Add Docker as mounted volume, so that Traefik can read the labels of another service
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      # Mount the volume to stor the certificates
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
    command:
      # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
      - --providers.docker
      # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on port 80
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on port 443
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      # Create the certificate resolver "le" for Let's Encrypt, uses the environment variable EMAIL
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${EMAIL?Variable not set}
      # Store the Let's Encrypt certificates in the mounted volume
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      # Use the TLS Challenge for Let's Encrypt
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
      - --accesslog
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api
    networks:
      # Use the public network created to be shared between Traefik and
      # any other service that needs to be publicly availible with HTTPS
      - traefik-public

volumes:
  # Create a volume to store the certificates, there is a constraint to make sure
  # Traefik is always deployed to the same Docker node with the same volume containing
  # the HTTPS certificates
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  # Use the previously created public network "traefik-public", shared with other
  # services that need to be publicly availible via this Traefik
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

And here is the **docker-compose.yml** file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build: ./
    restart: always
    labels:
      # === TLS ===

      # Enable Traefik for this specific "backend" service
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTP
      - traefik.http.routers.app-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.app-http.rule=Host(`gumbo.monster`)
      # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.app-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.app-https.rule=Host(`gumbo.monster`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app-https.tls=true
      # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver
      - traefik.http.routers.app-https.tls.certresolver=le
      # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # Middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.app-http.middlewares=https-redirect

      # === CORS ===

      # Only allow GET requests, as not other request is currently being implemented
      # - traefik.http.middlewares.testheader.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET
      # # Specify the the origins from which a resource can be shared
      # - traefik.http.middlewares.testheader.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=https://gumbo.co.uk,https://www.gumbo.co.uk
      # # Indicates how many seconds a preflight request can be cached for.
      # - traefik.http.middlewares.testheader.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100
      # # Adds the Vary demonstrate that server responses can differ based on the value of the origin header.
      # - traefik.http.middlewares.testheader.headers.addvaryheader=true

      # === DoS / DDoS ===

      # Limit the number of request that has been started but not yet completed, a.k.a. a request in progress.
      - traefik.http.middlewares.test-inflightreq.inflightreq.amount=10
      # Limit the maximum number of requests per second from a given source
      - traefik.http.middlewares.test-ratelimit.ratelimit.average=20
      # the maximum number of requests allowed to go through in the same arbitrarily small period of time.
      - traefik.http.middlewares.test-ratelimit.ratelimit.burst=1

    networks:
      # Use the public network created to be shared between Traefik and
      # any other service that needs to be publically available with HTTPS
      - traefik-public
    extra_hosts:
      # Allows a direct connection from inside a docker container to the local
      # machine on Linux based systems.
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

The only error log I am getting is with the certificate.

```
time="2023-08-30T15:33:44Z" level=error msg="Error renewing certificate from LE: {gumbo.monster []}" providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" error="error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[gumbo.monster] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:tls :: 76.76.21.21: remote error: tls: no application protocol\n"
```

Perhaps this could be the problem. I have made sure that both processes are running with `docker ps` and I have tried to check the **acme.json** file for certificate issues but couldn't find the file in my setup. I also tried running the whole thing over HTTP and ended up with the same issue.

I am all out of ideas. I would really appreciate any insights into debugging this issue further.

Thank you!